# Image transfer between master pc and slave Pc

Tags: camera, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am doing an telerobot, the camera was put on the slave pc, and from the master pc I can teleoperate the slave robot via vision feedback.

The prolem is that I configured the master and slave pc using ros, I can received image but i very very slow.I don't know the reason why??

Ps, I am using wifi for communication between master and slave

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10225/image-transfer-between-master-pc-and-slave-pc/) by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you subscribing to the images? If you're subscribing the raw image, the amount of data that has to be transferred could be quite large. Using one of the compressed transports (compressed or theora) may speed things up quite a bit. I'd suggest taking a look at the [image_transport](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport) wiki page to learn more.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on your requirements you can get very low bandwidth image transfer by lowering resolution and framerate as well as using compression. I got good results by using a webcam, setting it to 160x120 resolution, 5fps and Theora codec. "rostopic bw" tells me this config uses about 10kB/s for image transfer, which is pretty low.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1